# Unable to split Sparse Matrix into testing and training sets in R

Tags: r, sparse-matrix

I have a sparse matrix having around 200k columns and 200k rows. I need to split this matrix into 2 under training and testing data because I want to perform machine learning on the data. How do I do this?

Note: The sparse matrix I have is of class S4.

Comment: 200,000 columns (variables)?  And storing the matrix as sparse implies only a small percentage of variables are populated with values for each observation.  So while perhaps some clusters of variables sharing variable commonality could be identified, only the observations with common variables could be used in an ML model.  And clusters of observations not sharing common variables could not utilized in a single model.  I'm not sure how you could make this work even if you could split the data set.

Comment: Ok, it may not work, but atleast tell me how I can split the dataset